# How can I set the window position?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik

I'm using Jquery to open a new Telerik window, like:

```
var win = $('#myWindow').data('tWindow');
win.open();
```

I have the mouse position (x,y), and I want to open the window on same location.

How can I set the window position?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

open('btn','teste');

```
function open(div,data){

    var x = 50,
        y = 50;

    if($('#'+div).attr('data') == 'teste'){

        $('#'+div).attr( 'data', data).css({'top' : x, 'left' : y});

    }

}
```